# How to copy SVN repository as a folder to another repository with history

Tags: svn, repository, project

I have 2 repositories

```
http://mysnv/svn/proj1/trunk
```

- proj1_folder1
- proj1_folder2

and

```
http://mysnv/svn/proj2/trunk
```

- proj2_folder1
- proj2_folder2

How can I copy the *proj2* with history to be a **folder** in the trunk of *proj1* to get the following result

```
http://mysnv/svn/proj1/trunk
```

- proj1_folder1
- proj1_folder2
- proj2

  - proj2_folder1
  - proj2_folder2

Actually what I want to do is to have only one SVN repository with all the content of *proj2* and the history in the folder *proj2* in `http://mysnv/svn/proj1/trunk`

This is the SVN version I'm using:

> svn, version 1.7.8 (r1419691)

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976829/svn-copy-between-repositories-with-history) blog, but the svn merge is unclear to me. Where is it located `./foo/trunk:proj1`?

My svn folder structure is like `/data/svn/repos/` and I do not see the trunk folder.

I'm looking for a command to make the copy, without influencing my main project *proj1*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Physical aggregation**

- Create dumps of needed paths from proj2 repository (`svnadmin dump | svndumpfilter --include --include > dump` or `svnrdump URL-proj2_folder1 > dump1 & svnrdump URL-proj2_folder1 > dump2`)
- Load dump(s) into proj1 **with changed parent folder** (`svnadmin load --parent-dir trunk < dump`)
- Check presence of proj2_folder1's and proj2_folder2's data under **proj1/trunk/trunk** (second trunk is base path in dump of repo1)
- Rename child trunk-folder into proj2 (`svn mv`)

*Sample of loading svnrdump-ed trunk into new repo with parent dir `trunk/Project1`*

[image]

**Logical aggregation**

- Create proj1/trunk/proj2 folder
- Create two svn:externals (directory-type) inside proj2: proj2_folder1 linked to proj2/trunk/proj2_folder1
  and proj2_folder2 linked to proj2/trunk/proj2_folder2