# Create new SVN repository from checkout code (from dead SVN repo)

Tags: svn, repository, tortoisesvn, svn-repository, subversion-edge

I have checkout code from svn the repository was remote and is dead now, can I use it to create new SVN repository with history?

If yes, how can I do it?

If no, what are the other best way to handle this kind of situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An SVN checkout does not contain the history. The best you can hope for is a consistent, complete, somewhat recent snapshot of the latest state of the trunk. You probably also did not check out any tags or branches, right?

Comment: From a checkout you will only be able to restore the version you have last checked out. No more history. If you have sufficiently many backups, you could use them to build a "new history" (one revision from each backup copy) manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Thilo already mentioned,

> An SVN checkout does not contain the history. The best you can hope
>   for is a consistent, complete, somewhat recent snapshot of the latest
>   state of the trunk.

In order to create a new repository with the same history as the old one, you must have the working backup of the broken repository. You know what Subversion server package is installed on the remote location (the question is tagged with [subversion-edge](/questions/tagged/subversion-edge)), so I guess that you have access to the remote location. Search for the repository backup in such case.

It's unclear what you mean by "dead SVN repo", BTW. If a repository is corrupted (i.e. fails on `svnadmin verify`) then you can restore it partially (or even repair it). However, if you completely lost access to the repository and have no backup then you are out of luck.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I am not having an access to repository at all. I have some backup copies so I think that might help. Thanks for your answer.